# How to rename multiple files using .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects

I need to rename many jpg files. For expamle:

```
warszawa_1.jpg  ->  wars_1.jpg, warszawa_2.jpg  ->  wars_2.jpg
```

I created in the .htaccess file something like that:

```
Redirect 301 /img/warszawa_1.jpg        /img/wars_1.jpg
```

but I would have to enter over 100 like that. Is there any way to get it done with one entry in htaccess?

Comment: So, you are removing the `zawa` part of the original request URL? Are you linking to the `wars_N.jpg` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming:

1. You have already *renamed* these files in your application.
2. You are linking to the new filenames in your pages (otherwise you should not implement this as a redirect, but as an internal rewrite instead)
3. You have no other directives in your `.htaccess` file. (The order of directives is important and if you are already using mod_rewrite then you should probably use mod_rewrite instead.)
4. All these requests for images are for the `/img` subdirectory.

So, you are removing the `zawa` part of the filename and there are a series of digits after an underscore that need to be preserved.

Try the following:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^(/img/wars)zawa(_\d+\.jpg)$ $1$2
```

Test with 302 (temporary) redirects before changing to a 301 later if required.